express-session secure: true for production
app.use(session({
  secret: SESSION_SECRET || 'default-secret',  
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,  
      secure: true //for production, 
      maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000  
  }
}));

I'm working on some security problems on my newly developed web application. And after done some research online, if secure=true is set, then it will be more secure and it should be use for production only. However, If set secure: true, then information inside session will lose every time when the user send another request even in production as in production I am using https.Is there a way to solve this problem?
i tried secure: true //for production for production and also i am using https but it isn't working.

After some research i got fix to my problem. As in my code i am commenting the httpOnly:true which by default is true. so i have to define this as false not removing it from my code.
This works for me:
cookie:{
  httpOnly:false,
  secure:true
}


Setting httpOnly to false creates a vulnerability to XSS attacks; therefore, I do not recommend this solution.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If your application is running behind a reverse proxy (e.g., Nginx or Heroku), the Express application may interpret incoming HTTPS requests as HTTP. In this case, secure: true will prevent the session cookies from being sent.
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

